# Laravel 5 How to get all post input data in the format of json

Tags: json, laravel, input, get, laravel-5

I have created RESTful API and web application using laravel 5 .. I have created one Web service for register and the same function I'm trying to use in my web application.

If I use that function as web service, then my input parameter format should be json...
But in my web application inputs are parameter.  I can't able to getting problem to get my inputs...

I have tried

```
$post = file_get_contents ( "php://input" );
$data = json_decode ( $post, true );
return $data;
```

It has been return array in API call but web application return empty..

I tried below formats

```
Input::json()->all();
Input::all();
```

Nothing workout.

Comment: How are you posting the data? Can you also post the output of `$request->isJson()`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand You correctly, what You need is very simple:

```
return json_encode(Input::all());
```

To explain it more:

`Input::all()` - will give You an array with request parameters, that You can later turn into json
`file_get_contents ( "php://input" )` - will give You a query string, which after json_encode would be still a string

Answer (score 0):

If you are working for creating RESTFUL API, it is better return your result data as valid JSON, you can try like that:

```
   $data = json_encode(Input::all());
   return Response::json(['success' => true, 'data' => $data]);
```